# How to Create a LayoutInflator?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, layout-inflater

I used a constructor , But it doesn't work.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = new LayoutInflater(getContext());
```

Android Studio Underlines the following code in red

```
new LayoutInflater(getContext());
```

and it says "LayoutInflator is abstract; cannot be instantiated.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Please explain **in detail** what the problem is. The best way to get a `LayoutInflater` is to call `getLayoutInflater()` on your `Activity`.

Comment: I have updated my question based on what you asked.

Answer (score 3):

`LayoutInflater` is abstract class, so you can't just create it. You should use utility function `LayoutInflater.from(context)`.

Comment: Ok, This makes it ore clear , If it can't be directly called , why does it have a Constructor and what is the use of the constructor?As far as I know , Constructor is the only way to create an object instance of a class. How do I know which Class can't be made into an object with a constructor ?

Comment: @SarveshThiruppathi That's true. It has constructor because even if it's abstract class, it may need some arguments. Then what you do is extend that abstract class, and call it's constructor via `super` - in this case `super(context)`. Basically, you can only create object of classes that aren't declared `abstract`. Here, `LayoutInflater` is declared as: `public abstract class LayoutInflater`

Comment: So , there is a Super Class only because when we extend that class , we need to call super(context)